# Does anybody know what this tool is called?

Tags: sql-server

Productive work has crawled to a stop while we try and figure out what the red thing on the cover of Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Internals (2013, 0735658560) is. We think it's a surgical or electrical tool of some sort?

[image: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Internals]

Thoughts?

Comment: Look at other covers in the series. Chisel, hammer, screwdriver. A pattern emerges.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a pair of [canvas pliers](http://amzn.to/2ayNhA2). They're used to stretch canvas over braces, used in painting prep.

[image]

Answer source: Matt Velic, data professional and [noted art graduate](https://twitter.com/mvelic/status/758439079541346308).

Answer (score 6):

Specifically, it appears to be a Fredrix Canvas Pliers #7400 tool.
Here's a link to the manufacturers page (scroll to the bottom)  [Fredrix Canvas Pliers tool manufacturer](http://fredrixartistcanvas.com/explore-more/):

[image: Fredrix Canvas Pliers tool]

and a vendor page with a picture that more closely matches the book cover,  [Fredrix Canvas Pliers tool for sale](http://www.cheapjoes.com/fredrix-canvas-pliers.html). It looks like the spring has been removed from the tool on the book cover:

[image: Fredrix Canvas Pliers tool]

Answer (score 3):

It almost looks like a sheet metal seeming tool.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a sheet metal pliers.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it to be a PVC pipe cutter...

Comment: With a waffle finish?  You must be crazy.

Comment: Waffle finish? You must be hallucinating. I see you provided the correct solution. lol

Comment: What, flipping crazy... it must be those tools the ladies use to do something with their eyebrows!! Second guess is o[xxxx]::;;::;;::;;> Chainsaw!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a hand held paper hole punch, like the kinds we used to use when we were in grade school, with the blue flip lid trap door thingy that would catch the chads.

Answer (score -1):

It's the arm of a spot welding machine.

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything in that image that looks like the image in the question.